# Permission denied error

Tags: maven

I am new to java. I was assigned a task to fix some bugs in a java program. After I setup my environment and open the project. I got this error `An Ant BuildException has occured: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run:default:generate-resources)`.

I have already installed java, maven and ant. also I have added the mirror sites in the maven setting.xml file. Can someone help me on this?

Cheers

Comment: I doubt its related to settings.xml, can you paste the complete error trace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven All-of-a-sudden Receiving Permission Denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538401/maven-all-of-a-sudden-receiving-permission-denied)